# Failed to upload image to the created file

Tags: php, html

I'm uploading an image to a file named as 'uploads' which is in the same file as my PHP files. I always get an error message telling me `Undefined index`. What's the meaning of that error and how can I solve it?

This is the codes for my image upload form which I linked it to 'upload.php':

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="mutiplart/form-data">
    <div>   
        <input type="file" name="image" >
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload Image</button>           
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the `upload.php` file:

```
<?php
$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target = "uploads/".basename($image);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    } else {
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
}
?>
```

I expect the image uploaded will be saved in the 'uploads' file.

Comment: `enctype="mutiplart/form-data"` -> multipart..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
When asking a question like this, it is a good thing if you post the full error message if possible, helps a lot!

Comment: If your questions is only about what `Undefined index` means, the answer is: You are trying to access a index (or a key) in an array which does not exist (the index that is).

Comment: At which line it is giving `Undefined index`?

Comment: @Jite The error messages are like these:

Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Module4\Module4\Module4\upload.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Module4\Module4\Module4\upload.php on line 6

Comment: First off, I'd enable strict error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` on the second line after the `<?php` line, then you might get more descriptive errors.
Then I'd check my upload settings in the php.ini file and make sure that the file I upload is not to large for uploading.
Other than that, it looks like it should work (without testing the code myself, so could miss something I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the form attribute. Just change this `enctype="mutiplart/form-data"` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` then `Undefined index` error will no longer there.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. But i still get the error message like this

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Module4\Module4\Module4\upload.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Module4\Module4\Module4\upload.php on line 6

Comment: @JiasoonLoo I have verified the code on one of my servers and it works fine for me. Not sure exactly what you are doing wrong as the above code is correct except the typo I mentioned in the answer.